# Yocto Remove Chromium Package from Image

Tags: chromium, yocto

I'm working with a Yocto build and I'm trying to trim some fat off of it.  From my board-vendor-included layers include a chromium recipe.  I have no interest in using Chromium in our final image, and I've been trying to cut it out of the image.  So far, in my local.conf, I've tried the following:

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_remove += "chromium-browser"
IMAGE_INSTALL_remove += "chromium-wayland"
IMAGE_INSTALL_remove += "chromium"
PACKAGE_EXCLUDE = "chromium chromium-wayland chromium-browser"
```

And I have not had any success.  Every time I go back to build the image, chromium-wayland has attempted to compile.

Are there any other options to remove a package from an image?  Should I delete my directory of built packages and start over with these settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have completely override the remove command with +=; Please try this instead

`IMAGE_INSTALL_remove = " package package package "`

`PACKAGE_EXCLUDE` shall not be neccessary

For newer versions from kirkstone or above you should use `IMAGE_INSTALL:remove` instead of `IMAGE_INSTALL_remove`